# How do I minimize the space between a SearchBar in a NavigationView and the Text views above it?

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, searchbar

I'm trying to put two Text views above a SearchBar in a NavigationView. Is there a way to minimize the space between the SearchBar and the Text views above it? [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYD13.png).

Also, is my code optimal this way or can I implement all elements in one?

Find below a sample of what I've currently done.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
  
  @State private var searchText = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      
      Text("Hi There!")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.388, green: 0.231, blue: 1.0))
        .padding([.top, .leading])
      
      Text("Are you ready to work out?")
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .bold()
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .padding(.leading)
      
      NavigationView {
        
        Text("")
          .navigationTitle("Your Plans")
          .searchable(text: $searchText)
      }
      
    }
    
  }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Your Profile")
      .font(.largeTitle)
      .fontWeight(.heavy)
      .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
      .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.388, green: 0.231, blue: 1.0))
      .position(x: 125, y: 70)
    
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    TabView{
      HomeView()
        .tabItem {
          Text("Training")
            .foregroundColor(Color(red:0.388, green: 0.231, blue: 1.0))
        }
      
      SettingsView()
        .tabItem () {
          Image(systemName: "slider.vertical.3")
          
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.388, green: 0.231, blue: 1.0))
    }
    
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
      .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a NavigationView, you can do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var searchText = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 40) {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hi There!")
          .font(.largeTitle)
          .fontWeight(.heavy)
          .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
          .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.388, green: 0.231, blue: 1.0))
        Text("Are you ready to work out?")
          .fontWeight(.heavy)
          .bold()
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
        Text("Your Plans")
          .font(.largeTitle)
          .fontWeight(.heavy)
        SearchBar(text: $searchText)
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

struct SearchBar: View {
  @Binding var text: String
  @State private var isEditing = true
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 4) {
      Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
      TextField("Search", text: $text)
        .onTapGesture {
          self.isEditing = true
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 45)
    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
    .cornerRadius(15)
  }
}
```

PS: I have deliberately made the SearchBar view simple for brevity. You should add more functionality to it in a production application.